# Hidden buttons after app starts (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class named "Attendance" where I have many parameters and I have add button to every instance of attendance. 
I am adding many "attendances" into one list.

After the start of an application I do not want to see buttons there. They must be hidden. 
When the user hover over a row with the mouse the "change" button will appear. This works very good. Evert button is hidden also after the user 
is not hovering.

Problem is that I want to have buttons hidden also after the start of an app 
So maybe you have some ideas what I can put inside of the "initialize" because it is first method which runs after the start of an app.

Here are pictures:

1. after the start: 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc9uX.png
2. after "hover": 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3va4.png
3. after leaving table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mQ6e.png

---

public class Attendance {

```
private int studentId;
private Date date;
private String status;
Button changeAttendanceButton;

public Attendance(int studentId, Date date, String status) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.date = date;
    this.status = status;
    this.changeAttendanceButton = new Button("Change!!");

}



public Button getChangeAttendanceButton() {
    return changeAttendanceButton;
}

public void setChangeAttendanceButton(Button changeAttendanceButton) {
    this.changeAttendanceButton = changeAttendanceButton;
}



public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}



public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}



public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

Callback<TableColumn<Attendance, String>, TableCell<Attendance, String>> changeAttendanceCallback
            = //
            new Callback<TableColumn<Attendance, String>, TableCell<Attendance, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(final TableColumn<Attendance, String> param) {
            final TableCell<Attendance, String> cell = new TableCell<Attendance, String>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setText(null);
                    } else { 
                        changeAttendanceButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                            Attendance person = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                        });
                        setGraphic(changeAttendanceButton);
                        setText(null);

                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
```

}

public class SelectedStudentControler implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Attendance, Date> dateColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Attendance, String> attendanceColumn;

@FXML
private Label name;
@FXML
private Label month;
@FXML
private Label percentage;
@FXML
private Label takenL;
@FXML
private Label skuppedDay;
@FXML
private TableView<Attendance> studentTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Attendance, String> changeAttendanceColumn;


Date currentDate = new Date();
ModelManager manager = new ModelManager();



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 

    dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
    attendanceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));    
    changeAttendanceColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("changeAttendanceButton"));

    manager.loadAllAttendance();

    studentTable.setItems(manager.getAllAttendence());


    showChangeAttendanceButton();

}    


public void showChangeAttendanceButton() {
    studentTable.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
    final TableRow<Attendance> row = new TableRow<>();

        row.hoverProperty().addListener((observable) -> {
            final Attendance attendance = row.getItem();
            row.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");

            for (Attendance att : manager.getAllAttendence()) {

                if (row.isHover() && attendance == att) {

                    att.getChangeAttendanceButton().setVisible(true);
                    row.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#000;-fx-opacity: 0.7;");                  
                } 
                else {   
                    att.getChangeAttendanceButton().setVisible(false);

                }
            }               
        });
   return row;
    });
}
```

I want to achieve that first picture and third one will be same.
 I would be thankful for every solution.

Comment: Why not initializing it as `setVisible(false)` in the `Attendance` constructor ? Something like `this.changeAttendanceButton  = new Button("Change !!"); this.changeAttendanceButton.setVisible(false);`

Comment: @Pagbo thank you!! It is working!

Comment: Good. Just a remark it seems weird to me that your model (the `Attendance` class) gets a `Button` as attribute like `changeAttendance`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for remark too.